# Celery Task Grouping/Aggregation

Tags: python, asynchronous, task, celery, aggregation

I'm planning to use Celery to handle sending push notifications and emails triggered by events from my primary server.

These tasks require opening a connection to an external server (GCM, APS, email server, etc). They can be processed one at a time, or handled in bulk with a single connection for much better performance.

Often there will be several instances of these tasks triggered separately in a short period of time. For example, in the space of a minute, there might be several dozen push notifications that need to go out to different users with different messages.

*What's the best way of handling this in Celery?* It seems like the naïve way is to simply have a different task for each message, but that requires opening a connection for each instance.

I was hoping there would be some sort of task aggregator allowing me to process e.g. 'all outstanding push notification tasks'.

Does such a thing exist? Is there a better way to go about it, for example like appending to an active task group?

Am I missing something?

Robert

Comment: To clarify, this seems like I want the *opposite* of subtasks…individual tasks that are dispatched independently, but handled in aggregate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recently discovered and have implemented the `celery.contrib.batches` module in my project. In my opinion it is a nicer solution than Tommaso's answer, because you don't need an extra layer of storage.

Here is an example [straight from the docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.contrib.batches.html):

> A click counter that flushes the buffer every 100 messages, or every
> 10 seconds. Does not do anything with the data, but can easily be
> modified to store it in a database.

```
# Flush after 100 messages, or 10 seconds.
@app.task(base=Batches, flush_every=100, flush_interval=10)
def count_click(requests):
    from collections import Counter
    count = Counter(request.kwargs['url'] for request in requests)
    for url, count in count.items():
        print('>>> Clicks: {0} -> {1}'.format(url, count))
```

Be wary though, it works fine for my usage, but it mentions that is an "Experimental task class" in the documentation. This might deter some from using a feature with such a volatile description :)

Comment: very nice discovery! Just one point here
The reason you like it more (the not stored) does not apply imo, while docs dont explain how the batching is done, I see two possible ways: using the message broker or keeping in memory and be fine loosing flush_every-1 or flush_interval-1 worth of tasks if a worker crashes.

Comment: looking a bit closer at the docs it seems pretty clear that it is publishing to broker every single task (see notes about CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER) and the mark_as_done(task.id, task_result) and that when the worker gets enough tasks it executes them in one batch

Comment: I did set the prefetch multiplier to 0, without actually understanding it. @TommasoBarbugli thanks for making me read it :) It does seem like a potential problem, although one of the footnotes mentions "RabbitMQ and other brokers deliver messages round-robin, so this doesn't apply to an active system.". Not knowing celery or RabbitMQ, I don't understand if there is an actual problem with this setting being 0.

Comment: That page no longer exists; it would be nice if you updated it to the new one.

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to accomplish this is to write all the actions a task should take on a persistent storage (eg. database) and let a periodic job do the actual process in one batch (with a single connection).
Note: make sure you have some locking in place to prevent the queue from being processes twice!

There is a nice example on how to do something similar at kombu level (http://ask.github.com/celery/tutorials/clickcounter.html)

Personally I like the way sentry does something like this to batch increments at db level (sentry.buffers module)